# Drawing an arrow between 2 vertices to indicate the direction using bgl

Tags: python

I am trying to draw an arrow in between 2 vectors in an edge to simply represent the direction edge is going to. But I am getting weird results. Sometimes the arrow are perpendicular to the line itself and have odd rotation. What am I doing wrong? Please mind that this is orthographic projection of the top view, I have clicked the picture.

[image]

```
arrow_head = [
    [-1,-1],
    [0,0],
    [1,-1],
]

def draw_arrow_head(self, context, vecFrom, vecTo):
    ob = context.object
    if ob is None:
        return

    direction = Vector(vecTo) - Vector(vecFrom)
    direction.resize_2d()
    angle = direction.angle(Vector((0,1)))

    # form a 2d rotation matrix
    mat = Matrix().Rotation(angle, 2)

    # middle point
    middle = (Vector(vecTo) + Vector(vecFrom)) / 2.0

    bgl.glBegin(bgl.GL_LINE_STRIP)
    for v in arrow_head:
        xy = Vector(v)* 4.0 * mat
        xy.resize_3d()
        newPos = xy + middle
        bgl.glVertex3f(*newPos)
    bgl.glEnd()

def draw_edge_direction(self, context):
    ob = context.object
    if ob is None:
        return

    if bpy.context.active_object.mode != 'EDIT':
        return

    obj = context.edit_object
    me = obj.data

    bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

    for e in bm.edges:
        draw_arrow_head(self, context, e.verts[0].co, e.verts[1].co)
```

Comment: Will your context always allow a top down orthographic view?  If not please show the side view.  I suggest showing a circular form composed of small segments.

Comment: @yeah this is only for top down orthographic view.